# How can I read spark sql query execution plan and save it to a text file?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sql-execution-plan, explain

I want to read the spark sql query execution plan and save it to a text file for further analysis of logical and physical plan. how can I read it in such a way that it can be saved to a file. I am using **df.explain()** method but it just print the plan to cmd console. is there any way to **store it in String** or **directly save it to text file** or **extracting the plan from console**?

Comment: Perhaps this might help https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-QueryExecution.html

Answer (score 2):

you can store execution plan to a string this way:
if you have a `dataframe df` :

```
df.queryExecution.toString()
```

for logical plan:

```
df.queryExecution.logical.toString()
```

To see what exactly PySpark is calling underneath you can check https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.3/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html